# Proving $\prod_{i = 1}^n X_i \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{(\mathbb{P})} 0 \iff \prod_{i = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X_i}] = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am having a hard time proving the following :

> Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables which take their value in  $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ and such that  $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=1$ for all  $i \geq 1$. Then prove that :
> $$\prod_{i = 1}^n X_i \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{(\mathbb{P})} 0  \iff \prod_{i = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X_i}] = 0$$

Intuitively it seems quite natural since most of  the mass of the $X_i$ is on $[0,1]$. Taking the square-root just means we are concentrating further the mass of the $X_i$ around one. Thus it should go to zero.
Yet I don't know how to prove this result.

I tried taking the logarithm to manipulate sums yet doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I hope you are able to do if part ($\Leftarrow$) using Markov Inequality.

Comment: @annie_lee Yes. Also using the fact that if $\prod X_i$ converge in protobability to $0$ then so does $\prod \sqrt{Xi}$

Answer (score 1):

Declare a positive $\varepsilon$.
For any integer $n$, you can control $E[\sqrt{(\prod_i X_i)}]$ by separating the events $\prod_i X_i < \varepsilon$ and $\prod_i X_i \geq \varepsilon$.

The first term is bounded by $\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. For the second term, use Cauchy-Schwarz : $E[1_{\prod_i X_i \geq \varepsilon } \, .\sqrt{\prod_i X_i}] \leq \sqrt{P(\prod_i X_i \geq \varepsilon)} E[\prod_i X_i] = \sqrt{P(\prod_i X_i \geq \varepsilon)}$. The hypothesis tells you this term tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Yeah you are right....but $E(I_{\prod_i X_i \geq \epsilon}\sqrt{\prod_i X_i}) \leq E(\sqrt{\prod_i X_i})$. Then how will you conclude the result?

Comment: No, you use Cauchy-Schwarz to get a better inequality. As I wrote : $E[1_{\prod_i X_i \geq \varepsilon } \, .\sqrt{\prod_i X_i}] \leq \sqrt{P(\prod_i X_i \geq \varepsilon)} E[\prod_i X_i] = \sqrt{P(\prod_i X_i \geq \varepsilon)}$

Comment: $E(I_{\prod X_i \geq \epsilon} \sqrt{\prod X_i})\leq \sqrt{P(\prod X_i \geq \epsilon)} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow 0$        \\ $E(I_{\prod X_i \leq \epsilon} \sqrt{\prod X_i})\leq \sqrt{P(\prod X_i \leq \epsilon)} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow 0$........when you add  this two you get $E(\sqrt(\prod X_i))\leq 1$ but not zero.

Comment: You don't use Cauchy-Schwarz for the other inequality. You use the fact that, under the event $\prod_i X_i \leq \epsilon$, well, the random variable $\prod_i X_i$ is lesser than $\epsilon$. So, to sum up : You use the obvious bound for the first term, and Cauchy-Schwarz for the other one.

Comment: yeah I understand ..thanks

Comment: You're welcome !